# Fill empty slot with value by checking the line before

Tags: string, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, empty-list

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
day  value  
1 HSE  
2 HSE   
3  
4  
5  
6 LSE  
7 LSE  
8  
9  
10
```

Now, I want to fill the empty slots with values by checking the value before. So, I want 3,4,5 set to "fromHSE"and 8,9,10 "fromLSE".

I tried it like this:

```
e = "HSE"

for line in df:
    if df['value'] == "":
        if e == "HSE":
            df['value'] = "fromHSE"
        elif e == "LSE":
            df['value'] = "fromLSE"
    elif df['value'] == "HSE":
        e = "HSE"
    elif df['value'] == "LSE":
        e = "LSE"
```

But then i get the error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) empty string to `NaN`, create mask with [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html) and create new `Series` with `ffill`. Last add string `from` with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df.value.replace('',np.NaN, inplace=True)
mask = df.value.isnull()
new = df.value.ffill()
print (new.mask(mask, 'from' + new))
0        HSE
1        HSE
2    fromHSE
3    fromHSE
4    fromHSE
5        LSE
6        LSE
7    fromLSE
8    fromLSE
9    fromLSE
Name: value, dtype: object
```

Comment: But i got another dataframe that looks a bit different, so that method doesnt work.

Comment: Can you describe more what means `a bit different`? There are not empty strings?

Comment: So it is nearly the same but just with values like this:

day value
1 28.3
2 27.9
3 22.4
4 18.1    
5 15.5
6 7.1
7 5.1
8 12.0
9 15.1
10 10.1

Now HSE schould be over 25 and LSE below 8. Everything else is "Middle" but i want to know, if it was over 25 or below 8 before it went to "Middle".

Comment: Oh sorry for the style dont know why it made it like this

Comment: No problem. But I think the best is create new question. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry i have to ask again something because i get the error: TypeError: mask() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: I think there has to be some typo - do you use exactly my code or it is a bit modified? If yes, how do you modify it?

Comment: i use it like this:     SolarExplosure['Daily global solar exposure (MJ/m*m)'].replace('', np.NaN, inplace=True)
    mask = SolarExplosure['Daily global solar exposure (MJ/m*m)'].isnull()
    new = SolarExplosure['Daily global solar exposure (MJ/m*m)'].ffill()
    print(new.mask(mask, 'from' + new))

Comment: It looks nice. Is possible share your csv?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120078/discussion-between-madddin-and-jezrael).